# Finding specific seconds in a cell with time

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a column of times in hh:mm:ss format.  I need to identify each cell in the column that ends in :01 (XX:XX:01).  With Excel's time function, a =right(cell, 3) search doesn't find them.  Any thoughts how to strip off the :01 so it can be identified?

Am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Dates are stores as real numbers (day number + fraction of day for HH:MM:SS), so they would need to be converted to text before you could use `=right()`, but implicit conversion is to number format. It's much simpler to use the numeric function `=SECOND(cell)`.

Comment: That works great!  I created a macro that used your solution in a separate column, then searched that column for 1.  From there, it was easy manipulating the data I needed to in each row where the 1 was.  Many thanks!

Comment: I have expanded my comment as an answer, so others can see that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as real numbers (day number + fraction of day for HH:MM:SS): to verify this create a date and time cell (eg `A1` as `=NOW()`), then set `B1` to `=A1` and format as general numeric.

Before you can use `=right()`, a cell needs to be converted to text, but implicit conversion is to number format, regardless of the format set for the cell, so if you set `C1` as `=RIGHT(A1,3)` you will see that the last 3 digits of `B1` are returned.

The simple answer is to use the numeric function `=SECOND(A1)` and check if this is equal to the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the range of times to a new column as text, do a text to columns on the copied column using the ":" as the delimiter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to copy and paste times as text?  Thanks.